# How can i get Prettier and ESLint to work together?

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint, prettier

When using Sublime Text 3, how can I get the both to work together?

On file save, Prettier replaces single quotes with double quotes, whilst ESLint looks for single quotes.

How can I get the two packages to work together?

**.eslintrc**

```
{
      "parser": "babel-eslint",
      "extends": "airbnb",
      "plugins": [
        "react",
        "jsx-a11y",
        "import",
        "prettier"
      ],
      "rules": { 
        "no-use-before-define": 0,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-tabs": 0,
        "no-nested-ternary": 0,
        "indent": 0,
        "no-multi-assign": 0,
        "no-param-reassign": 0,
        "no-var": 0,
        "no-mixed-operators": 0,
        "no-unused-expressions": 0,
        "no-plusplus": 0,
        "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
        "no-case-declarations": 0,
        "vars-on-top": 0,
        "block-scoped-var": 0,
        "global-require": 0,
        "react/sort-comp": 0,
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
        "react/no-unused-prop-types": 0,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
        "react/no-array-index-key": 0,
        "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        "import/prefer-default-export": 0
      },
      "globals": {
        "window": true,
        "__DEV__": true,
        "expect": true,
        "it": true,
        "navigator": true,
        "fetch": true
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Prettier config uses double quotes by default and might conflict with the ESLint configs you have pulled in.

You can get them to work via these few ways (most recommended first):

1) Install [`eslint-config-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier) and extend from it in `.eslintrc`. Doing this turns off some of the formatting-related rules within ESLint that might conflict with Prettier.

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier"
  ]
}
```

2) Changing the `.prettierrc` config file

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  ...
}
```

3) Adding a command line option when you invoke Prettier

```
$ prettier --single-quote ...
```

4) Turn off ESLint's `quotes` rule within your `.eslintrc` config file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": "off",
   ...
  }
}
```